# When should a sentence start with the pronoun "it"?

Tags: pronouns, existentials, dummy-pronouns

As a spanish speaker, i sometimes have problems with the personal pronoun it.

Example:

> It can be dangerous to drive if you are tired.

The question is: How do I know when to start the sentence with "it"? Would it be correct if I say:

> Can be dangerous to drive if you are tired.

Comment: Have you read about the "dummy pronoun"?  If not, you should start there.

Comment: Is that your help?

Comment: Actually, **it** is not a personal pronoun. On the contrary it is quite [impersonal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impersonal_passive_voice).

Comment: I would say @Juhasz's comment is a full answer. If you need more explicit help, consider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun.

Answer (score 3):

This particular *`it`*, as noted, is a dummy pronoun -- i.e, it has no reference, it doesn't point to anything. 
It is in fact inserted by a syntactic rule called [Extraposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/419328/15299), which moves "heavy" subjects to the end of the sentence, where they can be processed more easily, and leaves a dummy *`it`* behind to satisfy the requirement that all tensed English clauses (including all simple sentences) have subjects.

In the example sentence

> - *It can be dangerous to drive if you are tired*.

several rules have applied:

1. The basic sentence would have been something like

   - *[For you to drive if you are tired] can be dangerous.*
     The bracketed part (an infinitive clause) is the subject, and *can be dangerous* is the verb phrase. This is a rather clumsy sentence; the predicate comes at the very end, which is not the way English likes sentences.
2. Extraposition would move the infinitive clause to the end, leaving dummy *`it`* behind.

   - *`It` can be dangerous [for you to drive if you are tired]*.
3. The subject of *drive* is the same as the subject of *are tired* -- indefinite *you* -- but it has been deleted.

   - *`It` can be dangerous [to drive if you are tired].*
     This is normal for indefinite subjects of infinitive clauses, unless the infinitive clauses themselves are subject clauses, as in (1) above. This is not allowed, however, with tensed clauses like *if you are tired* because tensed clauses must have subjects.

Comment: Thank you John for your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In Spanish, the subjects of sentences are often omitted.  The verb conjugations in Spanish are precise enough that the verb usually implies what the subject was.

In English, most of the verb conjugations are the same as each other.  Within each tense, most verbs only have a distinction between third-person singular and everything else.

Here is my advice to native speakers of Spanish who worry about making this mistake:  Always include a subject in every non-imperative sentence.  This will cause your speech and writing to be more formal than most native speakers.  If you cannot figure out what the subject is, consider using a "dummy pronoun" like "it" or "here" or "there".

In the previous paragraph:

- In the first sentence, "Here" is a dummy pronoun.
- The second sentence is imperative, so "You should" is implied.
- The third sentence uses "This" to refer to "includ[ing] a subject in every non-imperative sentence."

In the original post, the first example sentence is grammatically correct:

> It can be dangerous to drive if you are tired.

The second example sentence is incorrect:

> Can be dangerous to drive if you are tired.